# Problema em criar 2 matrizes n x m em C

Tags: c

Bom dia pessoal!
Estou fazendo um programa para criar e somar duas matrizes. Primeiro é informado o número de linhas e colunas, depois os valores dos elementos e depois as matrizes são somadas. Entretanto no meu código os elementos estão sendo repetidos e não estou conseguindo mudar isso. Estou fazendo em C. Alguem pode me ajudar? Segue meu código:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main (){
    
    int n, m;
    int mat[n][m],i,j;
    int mat2[n][m];
      
    printf ("Digite o tamanho das matrizes (n x m)\n");
    printf ("Tamanho da coluna (n): ");
    scanf ("%d", &n);
    printf ("\nTamanho da linha (m): ");
    scanf ("%d", &m);  


 
    if (n <=100 && m <= 100){
        
        printf ("\nDigite um por um os valores da matriz 1\n\n");
        
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ )
                {
                printf ("\nElemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf ("%d", &mat[i][j]);
            }
        }
        printf ("\nDigite um por um os valores da matriz 2\n\n");
          
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ )
                {
                printf ("\nElemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf ("%d", &mat2[i][j]);
            }
        }
            
        printf ("\n---------------saida---------------------\n");
        printf ("\n--------------matriz 1-------------------\n");
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
                for ( j=0; j<m; j++ )
            {
                printf ("\nElemento[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j,mat[i][j]);
            }
        }    
          
        printf ("\n--------------matriz 2-------------------\n");  
        
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ )
            {
                printf ("\nElemento[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j,mat2[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        printf ("\n--------multiplicação das matrizes----------\n");
        
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<m; j++){
            printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j,mat[i][j]+mat2[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }   else {
            printf ("\nMatriz muito grande, tamanho máximo 100 x 100\n");
        }   
      
  return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você declara as variáveis `n` e `m`, elas acabam já tendo valores, logo as suas matrizes acabam tendo um tamanho antes mesmo que você peça ao usuário o tamanho das mesmas.

---

Veja esse exemplo, apenas exibindo os valores de n e m sem ter feito o scanf:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
    
    int n, m;

    printf("Valor de n: %d\n", n);
    printf("Valor de m: %d\n", m);

    return(0);
}
```

> https://repl.it/repls/PutridUnripeAutomaticvectorization

---

Uma forma de corrigir, seria você declarar as matrizes após obter os valores de `n` e `m`:

```
int n, m, i, j;
  
printf("Digite o tamanho das matrizes (n x m)\n");
printf("Tamanho da coluna (n): ");
scanf("%d", &n);
printf("\nTamanho da linha (m): ");
scanf("%d", &m);  

int mat[n][m];
int mat2[n][m];
```

---

Com isso, seu código completo ficaria mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int n, m, i, j;
      
    printf("Digite o tamanho das matrizes (n x m)\n");
    printf("Tamanho da coluna (n): ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nTamanho da linha (m): ");
    scanf("%d", &m);  

    int mat[n][m];
    int mat2[n][m];
 
    if (n <=100 && m <= 100){
        
        printf("\nDigite um por um os valores da matriz 1\n\n");
        
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ ) {
                printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);
            }
        }

        printf ("\nDigite um por um os valores da matriz 2\n\n");
          
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ ) {
                printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = ", i, j);
                scanf("%d", &mat2[i][j]);
            }
        }
            
        printf("\n---------------saida---------------------\n");
        printf("\n--------------matriz 1-------------------\n");

        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ ) {
                printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j,mat[i][j]);
            }
        }    
          
        printf("\n--------------matriz 2-------------------\n");  
        
        for ( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
            for ( j=0; j<m; j++ ) {
                printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j,mat2[i][j]);
            }
        }
        
        printf ("\n--------multiplicação das matrizes----------\n");
        
        for (i=0; i<n; i++) {
            for (j=0; j<m; j++) {
                printf("\nElemento[%d][%d] = %d\n", i, j,mat[i][j]+mat2[i][j]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        printf("\nMatriz muito grande, tamanho máximo 100 x 100\n");
    }   
      
    return 0;
}
```

> https://repl.it/repls/GrossExoticScale

Comment: muito obrigado!